# How to replace angle brackets with quotation marks

Tags: linux, string, replace, awk, sed

I have a lot of source codes need modifying, simply as from

```
#include <headerA.h>
```

to

```
#include "headerA.h"
```

I've tried some sed, awk commands but not completely sure how to proceed this. I'm working on Ubuntu platform. Any inputs would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it:

```
sed -i '/^#include/s/[<>]/"/g' filename
```

The `/^#include/` address at the beginning tells `sed` to perform the substitution only on lines that begin with `#include`. `[<>]` is a regular expression that matches eith `<` or `>`, they get replaced with `"`, and the `g` modifier tells it to replace all the occurrences on the line, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

First use `find` with `sed` and then use `mv`

```
find . -name <ol_file_nme> -exec sed 's/[<>]/"/g' '{}' \; -print > <new_file_name>
mv  <new_file_name> <ol_file_nme>
```

Comment: el pluse uno for use of `find` but note @barmar's wise admonition and solution regarding other uses of the `<` and `>` characters ; -) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

This should edit each file in place:

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec \
    sed -i 's|^#include[[:blank:]]\{1,\}<\([^>]\{1,\}\)>[[:blank:]]*$|#include "\1"|' '{}' \;
```

Comment: just a remark, you loose the end of the evenutal information with the `.*$` not referenced later.

Comment: Yes, I should have used `[[:blank:]]*` there instead, to be perfectly correct. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/#include/y/<>/""/' file
```

Focus on lines that contain headers and translate (`y/.../.../`) the required characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /Your/Source/Path \
 -name '*.[ch]' \
 -exec \
    sed -i '/^#include[[:blank:]]/ s/<\([^>]*\)>/"\1"/g' "{}" \
 \;
```

will change:

- any file with extension `.h` or `.c` under `/Your/Source/Path`
- any surrounding text by `<>` with same text surrouonding by double quote

  - on line starting by `#include`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -E "s/^(#include )[\<]([^\>]+)[\>]/\1\\\"\2\\\"/g" sourcefile.c
```

or, as we don't need variable substitution inside the rule, with single quotes:

```
sed -i -E 's/^(#include )[\<]([^\>]+)[\>]$/\1"\2"/g'
```

Loop through all subdirectories of the working directory looking for *.c and *.h files and replace the angle brackets with quotation marks:

```
find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \) -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 sed -i -E 's/^(#include )[\<]([^\>]+)[\>]$/\1"\2"/g'
```